# Regex for unix ../ /.. /../

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am having php admin panel and pure-ftpd server running in the background.

I want to check if the path that user has provided for specific user DOES NOT contain ../ /.. or /../

I am using a php framework Nette and for this validation I am using addRule(Form::PATTERN, 'error message', $pattern) (Nette api-docs: https://api.nette.org/2.4/Nette.Forms.Form.html, Nette docs: https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/form-validation

Thank you for your time

Comment: I guess my question is, why would you allow a user to specify a server path? Whatever you're doing,  stop and think about how you can change that.

Comment: it is virtual path for webhosting, since we want clients to choose own root dir and have more ftp accounts.

i am just a coder, not the one who made this decision

Comment: What does this `../ /.. or /../` represent ? Concrete examples ?

Comment: Unix path system. So if you use ../ you will get to upper directory from the current one

Like in terminal:
/home/something/IAmHere: cd ../
/home/something

And the /.. and /../ are just variations

Comment: `I want to check if the path that user has provided for specific user DOES NOT contain ../ /.. or /../` would be `'~^(?!.*(?:\.\./|/\.\.)).+$~'`

Comment: @VojtaMareš - Btw, when you want to reply to an individual comment/question, prepend their name with an @ symbol, and take out all spaces in the name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're open to other solutions, but if it were me I would not attempt to use regex on the path because PHP has an easier way.

If it were me, I would do this:

```
<?php

// You know your users are limited to their own home directory
$user_base_dir = '/home/skunkbad/';

// And they supply some path that attempts directory transversal
$supplied_path = '/home/skunkbad/../../etc/';

// Realpath in this case would return "/etc/"
$realpath = realpath( $supplied_path );

// So the check to see if the user base directory is in the path that realpath returns would fail
if( stripos( $realpath, $user_base_dir ) !== 0 )
    echo 'Invalid Path!';
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

and: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @BrianGottier,

but `realpath($path)` checks if the file really exists in the filesystem and script need permission to execute... So, since I knew what I was looking for I googled and with some stuff from php.net & community i have came up with this:

```
/**
 * @param $path
 * @param $baseDir
 * @return bool
 */
protected function isDirValid($path, $baseDir)
{
    if (stripos($path, '\\'))
        return false;

    $path = str_replace('/', '/', $path);
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);

    $parts = array_filter(explode('/', $path), 'strlen');

    $absolutes = [];

    foreach ($parts as $part)
    {
        if ('.' == $part)
            continue;

        if ('..' == $part)
        {
            array_pop($absolutes);
        } else {
            $absolutes[] = $part;
        }
    }

    $realDir = '/' . implode('/', $absolutes);

    if (stripos($realDir, $baseDir) !== 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```